# How do I import stepCount from HealthKit API in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I'm currently struggling to understand the full idea of how get and display data from the HealthKit in SwiftUI. From what I've gathered so far, in order to allow my app to get the current steps the user has taken in the day, I do all of the authorization stuff, create quantity types etc, and in the function below, I have to query the data (this is the part I am struggling with). This is what I have for querying step count:

```
func retrieveSteps(completion: @escaping (Double) -> ()) {

 
        let date = Date()
              let cal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
              let newDate = cal.startOfDay(for: date)
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: newDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)

        var interval = DateComponents()
                interval.day = 1
        
        
        //Describing object type we want
        if let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount) {
            
            let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: newDate as Date, intervalComponents: interval)
            
            
            //Setting the results handler (need to query for the results 
            query.initialResultsHandler = {query, results, error in
                    
                if error != nil {
                    
                    print("error in stepTracker.swift, loading steps")
                    return
                }
                
                if let myResults = results{
                    //need to unwrap the HKCollections stuff
                    myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: <#T##Date#>, to: <#T##Date#>, with: <#T##(HKStatistics, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void#>)
                }
                
            }
        }
```

I am not particularly confident in the way I am querying the data, but I am mostly confused on how to get the result as single value for whenever I want to call the function (hence why the result area is pretty much incomplete)